# MSAL4J AcquireTokenSilently without Specifying Scopes

Tags: azure-ad-msal

I need to refresh the access token with `acquireTokenSilently` but I don't want to specify `scopes` in `SilentParameters`. I want to refresh it for all possible scopes which are founded in `TokenCache` object also.

So, can I reach scopes in the `TokenCache`? and then I can pass s `SilentParameters`. Or is there another way for this?

For example like below, It was passed `"User.Read"` however I don't want to specify any scope. I only want refresh my current access token(which is also founded in `TokenCache`) silently. How can I do that?

```
app.tokenCache().deserialize(sampleTokenCache);
SilentParameters parameters = SilentParameters.builder( Collections.singleton("User.Read"),result.account()).build();
CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> future = app.acquireTokenSilently(parameters);
IAuthenticationResult updatedResult = future.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh your current access token by similarly how you requested the token (id or access) in the first place when you requested the token. Then you need to detect the expired token and requests a new token. You can learn more about refresh tokens [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#refreshing-tokens).